# 3 table authentication in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel

can we do a 3 table authentication in laravel 5.2 like i have role for Admin, Teacher, Student and i want authentication for these 3 tables separately

At this time i have 2 table and these are authenticated separately and working fine

this is my code for auth.php

```
'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'user',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'user' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users'
        ],
        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admins'
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],

'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],

        'admins' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Admin::class,
        ]
    ],

'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'email' => 'auth.emails.password',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
        'admins' => [
            'provider' => 'admins',
            'email' => 'admin.auth.emails.password',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
    ],
```

AdminController.php file is look like

```
class AdminController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct(){
        $this->middleware('admin');
    }

    public function index(){
        // return Auth::guard('admin')->user();
        return view('admin.dashboard');
    }

    public function Profile()
    {
        $adminData = Auth::guard('admin')->user();
        return view ('admin.add', compact('adminData'));
    }
}
```

HomeController.php file is here

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('auth.dashboard');
    }
}
```

Route file is look like this

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function(){
    Route::auth();
    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
});

Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    //Login Routes...
    Route::get('/admin/login','AdminAuth\AuthController@showLoginForm');
    Route::post('/admin/login','AdminAuth\AuthController@login');
    Route::get('/admin/logout','AdminAuth\AuthController@logout');

    // Registration Routes...
    Route::get('admin/register', 'AdminAuth\AuthController@showRegistrationForm');
    Route::post('admin/register', 'AdminAuth\AuthController@register');

    Route::get('/admin', 'AdminController@index');
    Route::get('/profile', 'AdminController@Profile');
});
```

Now i want to add another table and do builtin authentication for this new table

Comment: yes you can do this, you have to add guard and providers for particular user type(Student,Teacher etc)

Comment: i am new in laravel can you help me to do it